# Not validating new controls after submitting form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-if

We have a form which we are submitting on save button. There are some validation firing on save. We are submitting form using `$scope.isSubmitted= true` and `$scope.watch` on `$scope.isSubmitted` for error highlighting

After submitting and validating the form, if there is any new controls add to form on the basis of `ng-if` condition the new controls are also validated. So my question is how to prevent new controls which being added after submitting the form to validate and only validate after resubmit.

Comment: Please provide current status as fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you add new "controls", you update your scope which is then re-evaluate. `$scope.isSubmitted` being true (and maybe `yourForm.$submitted` too) new values are verified on the fly.

Setting `$scope.isSubmitted` & `yourForm.$submitted` to false before adding "controls" should solve your issue.